# Bubble Sort Output Problems in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I'm currently studying a chapter of a C textbook on Array of Pointers/Dereferencing on Strings. It provides this example of a bubble sort on strings. And each time I run it, it doesn't output the strings in alphabetical order, ascending, including every character of the strings. I keep rereading the code to figure out where the bug is, but can't find it. Here is the textbook provided source with the output:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define SIZE 8

int main()
{
    const char *name[] =
    {
        "Mickey",
        "Minnie",
        "Donald",
        "Daisy",
        "Goofy",
        "Chip",
        "Dale",
        "Pluto"
    };
    const char *temp;
    int x,a,b;

    for(a=0; a<SIZE-1; ++a)
    {
        for(b=a+1; b<SIZE; ++b)
        {
            x=0;
            while(*(*(name+a)+x))
            {
                if(*(*(name+a)+x) > *(*(name+b)+x))
                {
                    temp = *(name+a);
                    *(name+a) = *(name+b);
                    *(name+b) = temp;
                    break;
                }
                else if(*(*(name+a)+x) < *(*(name+b)+x))
                {
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    x++;
                }
            }
        }
        for(x=0; x<SIZE; ++x)
        {
            printf("%s\n",*(name+x));
        }
        return(0);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Chip
Minnie
Mickey
Donald
Goofy
Daisy
Dale
Pluto
```

Comment: Just for your information, for *any* pointer or array `a` and index `i`, the expression `*(a+i)` is *exactly* equal to `a[i]`. Note that `a[i]` is easier to read and understand, and also less to write.

Comment: I agree; but I think the point of the chapter is on using exclusively pointer notation.

Comment: Since you have a compiler, you should have an IDE that you can use to test it.  Try single stepping through it, I suspect that'll show where the error is.

Comment: So you're asking where is the textbook wrong? Are you sure that you correctly copied the source code from the textbook?

Comment: No.  I have a suspicion there's an error in your transcription of the code from the textbook.-- Edit - user202729 beat me to it. :)

Comment: After formatting the error is obvious: The output is after first run of outer loop - too early. The output loop has to be moved outside of outer loop. See [Live Demo on Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/JgEiqNc2zVK8luhm)

Comment: If your textbook has the same terrible formatting like your original posted code (where it is impossible to recognize right or wrong nesting of loops) then throw it away... ;-)

Comment: If you don't want to use an IDE then I recommend warmly to become familiar with `gdb`. It can be used in shell without any GUI chicky micky - it needs a bit time to get used but is as powerful as any visual debugger. On the other hand, after having used WinDbg and VS, I don't want to use `gdb`/`dbx` anymore. (I clearly became addicted to the former...)

Comment: The output loop is indeed the problem, Scheff. My transcription of the code was actually incorrect. The textbook does indent/space the inner loops more than I did in the original post, sorry. Thanks.

Comment: Also, thanks for the formating advice, Scheff. I will start doing that now.